# hhvm extension loaded but can't find function

Tags: php, hhvm

I am trying to use the geoip extension of HHVM. I followed all instructions and installed it on my development machine and everything works fine. Then I deploy it to my live server and everything goes wrong.

I know that the extension is loaded on the live server because:

```
root@live:~/hhvm# hhvm --php -r 'print_r(get_loaded_extensions());'
Array
(
    [0] => apc
    [1] => array
    [2] => asio
    [3] => async_mysql
    [4] => bcmath
    [5] => bz2
    [6] => collections
    [7] => ctype
    [8] => curl
    [9] => date
    [10] => debugger
    [11] => dom
    [12] => domdocument
    [13] => enum
    [14] => exif
    [15] => fb
    [16] => fileinfo
    [17] => filter
    [18] => gd
    [19] => generator
    [20] => geoip
    [21] => hash
    [22] => hh
    [23] => hh_client
    [24] => hhvm.debugger
    [25] => hhvm.ini
    [26] => hosthealthmonitor
    [27] => hotprofiler
    [28] => iconv
    [29] => idn
    [30] => imagick
    [31] => imap
    [32] => intervaltimer
    [33] => intl
    [34] => json
    [35] => ldap
    [36] => libxml
    [37] => mail
    [38] => mailparse
    [39] => mbstring
    [40] => mcrouter
    [41] => mcrypt
    [42] => memcache
    [43] => memcached
    [44] => mysql
    [45] => mysqli
    [46] => objprof
    [47] => openssl
    [48] => pcntl
    [49] => pcre
    [50] => pdo
    [51] => pdo_mysql
    [52] => pdo_sqlite
    [53] => phar
    [54] => posix
    [55] => readline
    [56] => redis
    [57] => reflection
    [58] => server
    [59] => session
    [60] => SimpleXML
    [61] => soap
    [62] => sockets
    [63] => spl
    [64] => sqlite3
    [65] => standard
    [66] => stream
    [67] => string
    [68] => sysvmsg
    [69] => sysvsem
    [70] => sysvshm
    [71] => thread
    [72] => thrift_protocol
    [73] => tokenizer
    [74] => url
    [75] => wddx
    [76] => xenon
    [77] => xhprof
    [78] => xml
    [79] => xmlreader
    [80] => xmlwriter
    [81] => xsl
    [82] => zip
    [83] => zlib
)
```

But I always get this error on live:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_country_code_by_name() in
```

Then I also tried running this on the console:

```
hhvm --php -r 'print_r(geoip_country_code_by_name("www.google.com"));'
> US
```

Then I also tried `phpinfo()` and executed it on the browser which showed me:

```
hhvm.dynamic_extensions Array ( [0] => geoip.so )
```

Obviously this means that it is actually loaded on the environment of nginx. I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: see http://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.setup.php

Comment: @SimoneNigro, see nothing that helps. Like I said, I already have it fully running on my dev machine, but not on my live machine. I did the same procedure to install on both machines.

Comment: _“I know that the extension is loaded on the live server”_ – PHP CLI and PHP embedded into the web server often use different configuration files – so go check which one is used when you run your PHP via the web server (assuming you have this problem in the latter situation, whereas it works fine from console.) Use `phpinfo()` in a script that you call via your web server – that will tell you if the extension is actually loaded _in that environment_, and will also tell you which configuration file is used.

Comment: @CBroe `phpinfo()` of hhvm doesn't include any information about config files.